# Java or Nodejs as consumer for RabbitMQ

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

Which technology, Java or Nodejs is more appropriate for consumer of `RabbitMQ` that main task is to get and store json messages in `MongoDB` ?

More details:

My application have frontend (angular+sailsjs+nodejs+mongodb). Data should be provided from `RabbitMQ` to mongodb with very little calclations. Because I already have mongodb working with frontend, it's maybe obvious(or nor?) to reuse nodejs. But maybe there is some pros for use Java for storing messages in db. (Also look for excuse for use another technology)

Comment: Honestly either would work fine for what you want.  It sounds like whatever you're wanting will pretty much just be a pass through.  My opinion is that you should try to minimize complexity - if you're already using a Node.js stack then I'd stick with that.